# Issues with 'self' argument and python requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-requests, self

Having an issue calling function `dynamic_exit` from class `dynamic`, called from an imported python file within the project file. Only including enough code to depict an efficient example of my issue.

Call example below:

```
from lib.core import dynamic
import ...

if requests.get(url).status_code != 200:
    clear()
    print(" xxxxx \n\n\n")
    print("[ !! | Invalid URL ] Status code: {0}".format(
                                                str(requests.get(url).status_code)))
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n\n Please enter a valid URL.\nExiting...")
    dynamic.dynamic_exit(self=dynamic())
    time.sleep(3)
    exit()
```

`Lib.core` contains:

```
class dynamic:

    def __init__(self):
        self.loadSwitch = False
        self.analyzeSwitch = False
        self.exitSwitch = False

    def dynamic_load(self, loadSwitch=True):
        self.loadSwitch = loadSwitch
        done = False
        for c in itertools.cycle(['[ | ]', '[ / ]', '[ - ]', '[ \\ ]']):
            if done:
                break

        sys.stdout.write('\rLoading ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

# Further along...
if dynamic.dynamic_analyze(): # Separate function -- Irrelevant
    t = threading.Thread(target=dynamic_analyze())
    t.start()
elif dynamic_exit(): # Separate function -- Irrelevant
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=dynamic_exit())
    t2.start()
else: # dynamic_load -- Example function
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=dynamic_load())
    t3.start()

sys.stdout.write('\r[ ✓ ] Process Complete ')
time.sleep(4.5)

done = True
loadSwitch = False
exitSwitch = False
analyzeSwitch = False
```

Lord, I know it's a mess. First time actually working with classes like this.

Error is as follows:

```
  File "~/test-delete.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lib.core import dynamic
  File "~/lib/core.py", line 55, in <module>
    if dynamic.dynamic_analyze():
TypeError: dynamic_analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

The IDE is wanting more than a simple `self` parameter, it is recommending `self=`. So unsure of how to handle this.

Basically, need help under the context of the `__init__` function and using the `self` parameter. Trying to call the function setting either `exitSwitch`, `analyzeSwitch`, or `loadSwitch` = `True`, if`switch == True`, perform either function `dynamic_load`, `dynamic_exit`, or `dynamic_analyze`. Post-completion, set all switches back to `False`.

Comment: Are you getting a specific error? There seems to be indentation problems with the code you've posted

Comment: You **must** provide properly indented code, it is part of the syntax of python

Comment: Anyway, why are you trying to do `dynamic.dynamic_exit(self=dynamic())` ? Why not instantiate the class and call the method normally?

Comment: Sorry about this guys, making some edits right now. Sec... Error is as follows: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/test-delete.py", line 11, in <module>
    from lib.core import dynamic
  File "~/lib/core.py", line 55, in <module>
    if dynamic.dynamic_analyze():
TypeError: dynamic_analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling instance methods as if they are static methods. In other words, you call the methods as `dynamic.dynamic_analyse()` where `dynamic` is a reference to the *class*, not to an *instance* of that class.

So proceed as follows:

- Name your class with PascalCase -- a common practice to distinguish classes from other things. So yours should be named `Dynamic`.
- Create an instance and assign it to a variable. This one could actually get the name `dynamic` with lower case initial letter.
- Don't pass an instance as argument when calling methods *on the instance*. Because in the notation `a.b()`, `b` will be called with the value for `self` set to `a`.

So define the class as:

```
class Dynamic:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loadSwitch = False
        self.analyzeSwitch = False
        self.exitSwitch = False

    # ...etc.
```

Import the class and create an instance like this:

```
from lib.core import Dynamic

# ...

dynamic = Dynamic()  # Create instance

# ...

if dynamic.dynamic_analyze():  # Call method on the instance
    # ..etc
```

Your exit code should have:

```
dynamic.dynamic_exit()  #  No argument.
```

I cannot comment on the rest of your code, as it is hard to tell what it is doing. For instance, I do wonder why you call `dynamic_analyse()` twice... but this at least will solve the problem with the error you got.